# Set namespace prefix in jackson POJO

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

In a *Spring Boot 2.7.7* application using *jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml and jackson-datatype-jsr310* I want to generate this XML with namespaces and, more important, the prefix n1 (must be this one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" ?>
<n1:EventMessage
      xmlns:n1="http://we.com/2016/path/Types">
   <n1:Header>
      <n1:EventID>eventid</n1:EventID>
      <n1:EventTime>eventTime</n1:EventTime>
   </n1:Header>
</n1:EventMessage>
```

For this I have two POJOs:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "EventMessage", namespace = "http://we.com/2016/path/Types")
public class EventMessage {
    @XmlElement(name = "Header")
    private Header header;
}
```

```
public class Header {

    @XmlElement(name = "EventID")
    private String eventId;

    @XmlElement(name = "EventTime")
    private String eventTime;
```

and try to generate with:

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(eventMessage);
```

what I get is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" ?>
<EventMessage
      xmlns="http://we.com/2016/path/Types">
   <Header>
      <EventID>eventid</EventID>
      <EventTime>eventTime</EventTime>
   </Header>
</EventMessage>
```

How can I add the *n1:* prefix and add the *:n1* to xmlns?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it the way you are describing it with `namespace` attribute. It needs be custom element `xmlns:n1` not namespace

Comment: custom element doesn't sound familiar. Can you please add an example?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the following

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "n1:EventMessage")
public class EventMessage {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "xmlns:n1")
    private String xmlns = "http://we.com/2016/path/Types";
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "n1:Header")
        private Header header;

    public Header getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(Header header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
}
```